# Cannot convert from int to boolean

Tags: java, int, boolean

```
private static boolean allNinePresent(int[][] array){

    int total = 0;

    for (int row = 0; **array.length**; row++){
        for (int col = 0; **array[row].length**; col++){

            int addEach = array[row][col]; 
            total = addEach + total;


        }           
    }

    if (total == 45){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Shouldn't the array be an int? Why is it converting it from an int to boolean? How can I fix this.

Comment: Bahh thank you. Kept over looking the simple stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed in [official tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) for statement looks like

```
for (initialization; termination; increment) {
    statement(s)
}
```

and

> When the `termination` expression evaluates to `false`, the loop terminates.

In your case `*array.length` is used in place of termination, but in Java booleans can't be represented by integers, so something like `if(1)` is not valid. This means that you need to be more specific and use actual expression which can be evaluated to boolean (true or false), like

- `true`
- `false`
- `a<b`
- `a>=b`

That is why your loops should look more like

`for (int row = 0; row<array.length; row++){`
`for (int col = 0; cor<array[row].length; col++){`

---

BTW

```
if (total == 45){
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

can be rewritten to something simpler like

```
return total == 45;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int col = 0; array[row].length; col++){
```

second part accepts a `boolean` expression,

```
; array[row].length;
```

you are passing `int`

you need

```
row < array.length
```

and

```
col < array[row].length
```

Answer (score 0):

The second part of the `for` loop isn't the stopping *value*, it's the *condition* under which the loop will continue looping.  Use `row < array.length` and `col < array[row].length`.